# CGAL performance locally vs in WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, c++, cgal

I am trying to use CGAL within a webpage by compiling it into web assembly. Right now I am just messing around and trying to understand what the possibilities are.

I was worried about the speed of CGAL so I made a little benchmark to understand how fast the library is.

```
Nef_polyhedron N1(P);
Nef_polyhedron initial(P);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
            printf("i:  %i\n", i);
            Nef_polyhedron N2(initial);
            N2 = translate(N2,2*i,2*j,2*k);
            N1 += N2;
        }
    }
}
```

Which generates a cube of cubes like this:

[image: Cube of cubes benchmark]

When I compile that code locally into a .exe file the execution time is fantastic ~3 seconds which is perfect for what I want.

However when I compile the code into WebAssembly and run it in a browser it takes 143 seconds to run which is long. I expect somewhat of a performance hit when going to WebAssembly, but that seems huge.

Can anyone help me understand what is going on? I appreciate any thoughts anyone has.

I am using the simple Cartesian kernel and I am interested in doing boolean operations. Here is my complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/polygon_mesh_processing.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>     Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel>         Polyhedron;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                    Point_3;
typedef Polyhedron::Halfedge_handle        Halfedge_handle;
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex_iterator        Vertex_iterator;
typedef Polyhedron::Facet_iterator                   Facet_iterator;
typedef Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_facet_circulator Halfedge_facet_circulator;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_polyhedron;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3  Vector_3;
typedef Kernel::Aff_transformation_3  Aff_transformation_3;


template <class Poly>
typename Poly::Halfedge_handle make_cube_3( Poly& P) {
    // appends a cube of size [0,1]^3 to the polyhedron P.
    CGAL_precondition( P.is_valid());
    typedef typename Poly::Point_3         Point;
    typedef typename Poly::Halfedge_handle Halfedge_handle;
    Halfedge_handle h = P.make_tetrahedron( Point( 1, 0, 0),
                                            Point( 0, 0, 1),
                                            Point( 0, 0, 0),
                                            Point( 0, 1, 0));
    Halfedge_handle g = h->next()->opposite()->next();             // Fig. (a)
    P.split_edge( h->next());
    P.split_edge( g->next());
    P.split_edge( g);                                              // Fig. (b)
    h->next()->vertex()->point()     = Point( 1, 0, 1);
    g->next()->vertex()->point()     = Point( 0, 1, 1);
    g->opposite()->vertex()->point() = Point( 1, 1, 0);            // Fig. (c)
    Halfedge_handle f = P.split_facet( g->next(),
                                       g->next()->next()->next()); // Fig. (d)
    Halfedge_handle e = P.split_edge( f);
    e->vertex()->point() = Point( 1, 1, 1);                        // Fig. (e)
    P.split_facet( e, f->next()->next());                          // Fig. (f)
    CGAL_postcondition( P.is_valid());
    return h;
}


float displayBuffer[1000];

Nef_polyhedron translate(Nef_polyhedron shape, int x, int y, int z){
    
    Aff_transformation_3 aff(CGAL::TRANSLATION, Vector_3(x, y, z));
    shape.transform(aff);
    
    return shape;
}

extern "C"
{

int displayShape(){
    
    time_t start, end; 
    start = time(NULL);
    
    Polyhedron P;
    Halfedge_handle h = make_cube_3( P);
    
    Nef_polyhedron N1(P);
    Nef_polyhedron initial(P);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
                printf("i:  %i\n", i);
                Nef_polyhedron N2(initial);
                N2 = translate(N2,2*i,2*j,2*k);
                N1 += N2;
            }
        }
    }
    
    Polyhedron P2;
    N1.convert_to_polyhedron(P2);
    
    
    printf("Facets before: %lu\n", P2.size_of_facets());
    
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces(P2);
    
    printf("Facets after: %lu\n", P2.size_of_facets());
    
    end = time(NULL); 
    printf("Time compute cube is %.2f seconds\n", difftime(end, start)); 
    
    int index = 0;
    
    for (  Facet_iterator i = P2.facets_begin(); i != P2.facets_end(); ++i) {
        
        Halfedge_facet_circulator j = i->facet_begin();
        
        Vertex_iterator v = j->vertex();
        
        displayBuffer[index] = v->point()[0];
        displayBuffer[index+1] = v->point()[1];
        displayBuffer[index+2] = v->point()[2];
        
        j++;
        
        Vertex_iterator w = j->vertex();
        
        displayBuffer[index+3] = w->point()[0];
        displayBuffer[index+4] = w->point()[1];
        displayBuffer[index+5] = w->point()[2];
        
        j++;
        
        Vertex_iterator x = j->vertex();
        
        displayBuffer[index+6] = x->point()[0];
        displayBuffer[index+7] = x->point()[1];
        displayBuffer[index+8] = x->point()[2];
        
        index = index + 9;
    }
    
    return index;
}

float * getDisplayBufferAddress(){
    return displayBuffer;
}

}


// Init circle data and start render - JS
int main(){

    
    printf("Loading new...\n");
    
    EM_ASM({ init(); });
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Some information from profiling

When I profile the loading process you can pretty clearly see the pattern of each cube processing and the process taking longer and longer as the shape gets more and more complex:

[image: Profiling]

Unfortunately there doesn't (at least to my eye) seem to be one particular function which is taking an unexpected amount of time...more that they are cumulatively taking longer than expected.

Comment: It looks like it is possible to profile an application in webassembly. That could give a hint.

Comment: That is an excellent suggestion. Thank you. I will start profiling it and see what I can learn.

Comment: At least to my eye the profiling looks pretty much the way it should. I don't see one stand out culprit. Is there some what the core math like 1+1 could be being computed differently in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that the emcc optimization makes a HUGE difference here for some reason. CGAL without the optimization is slow in the browser, but with the optimization it is pretty close to running natively.

Adding the -O2 compiler flag took my benchmark time from 143 seconds down to 5 seconds.

https://emscripten.org/docs/optimizing/Optimizing-Code.html

Hope this helps someone someday!

Comment: Isn't the same true with the native build?

Comment: I guess that would probably be the case, but maybe g++ and visual studio optimize more by default? I was seeing good performance with both visual studio and g++ without specifically setting any flags.

Comment: To clarify, I don't have much experience with C++ so this might be something which would have been obvious to someone with more experience